# GitHub - Branch

Tags: github

Bom dia pessoal!
Existe um repositorio no gitHub com 02 branch: (Master e Develop).
Eu clonei a branch Master no meu ambiente local e apartir desta branch Master eu criei a feature-melhorias, entretanto, a branch que está atualizada no gitHub é a Develop.

Duvida: Como faria pra ter acesso a branch Develop e criar outra apatir dela no meu local?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois que você clonou o repositorio para mudar de branch você pode utilizar o comando

```
git checkout develop
```

Para criar uma branch a partir dessa branch você pode utilizar o comando:

```
git checkout -b feature/{nome-da-sua-branch}
```

Comment: quando executo o ```git checkout develop ``` aparece o seguinte error ```error: pathspec 'feature/teleconsulta' did not match any file(s) known to git.```

Comment: @SenaOliveira, você pode utilizar `git remote update`, `git fetch` e `git switch develop`

Comment: Agora deu certo!!!  executei o ```git remote update``` e foi!! Obrigado!!!!